# My CollectionViewSource is not picking up changes

Tags: c#, wpf, collectionviewsource

I have a ListView which I'm binding to a CollectionViewSource in code behind with:

```
collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(TableView.ItemsSource);
collectionView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
collectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(propertyName, direction));
```

The TableView is the ListView, the propertyName is the name of the column I want sorted, and direction is either ascending or descending.

The XAML has the following for ItemSource:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}"
```

The code behind has the following for the Rows:

```
List<TableRow> rows;

public List<TableRow> Rows
{
    get { return rows; }
    set 
    {
        rows = value;
        UpdateProperty("Rows");
    }
}
```

the update is as follows:

```
public void Update()
{
     ...generate a list of rows...

     Rows = ...rows...
}
```

The problem occurs when the Update is called, the list view does update, but loses the sorting set previously on the CollectionViewSource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are "newing" rows then any setting on the prior rows is gone.   If you clear (not new) the rows then I think they will hold the setting.

And you don't even want Rows = rows in update.
After assign rows then.

```
NotifyPropertyChange("Rows");
```

So the UI know to update

If you are going to new then reassign

```
collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(TableView.ItemsSource);
collectionView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
collectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(propertyName, direction));
```

Maybe

```
private List<TableRow> rows = new List<TableRow>();
```

and have that the only place you new it

Comment: Unfortunately, using Rows = rows is a requirement for what I'm working on.

Comment: @imekon And just why is Rows = rows a requirement?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to reapply the sort descriptions after the update, as in:

```
collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(TableView.ItemsSource);  
collectionView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
collectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(propertyName, direction));
```

Then the sorting isn't lost. Refresh on the collection view doesn't help.

Comment: That is exactly what I said in my answer 23 hours ago.   If you are going to new then reassign ...

Comment: That's true, I was hoping Refresh or something simpler would do it.

Answer (score 2):

> If an item property value involved in one of the grouping, sorting and filtering operations is
>   updated, then the sorting/grouping/filtering will not be done again.
>
> WPF 4.5 introduce a feature called live shaping which shapes the
>   collection view in live.

See [this article](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/10/05/wpf-4-5-%E2%80%93-part-10-live-shaping/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do `CollectionView.Refresh()` after your update?

If this does not help then I think your problem occurs because you change the source of your `CollectionView` by assigning new value to your `Rows` list.

I don't know if it is possible to your code but don't assign new list just clear your previous one and insert new rows there.

```
if (Rows != null)
   Rows.Clear();
   Rows.TrimExcess();
else
   Rows = new List<TableRow>();
```