# WPF Datagrid: ListCollectionView sorting does not seem to work after Data is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid, listcollectionview

My `DataGrid`'s `ItemsSource` is a `ListCollectionView`, which has a `GroupDescription` and two `SortDescriptions`. On the first run of the program, everything works as it should.

However, when the data the `ListCollectionView` is based on gets changed, the sorting of the `ListCollectionView` fails (whereas the `Grouping` does not). It behaves as if the two lines marked as "LINE A" and "LINE B" were not there at all.

```
public List<MyModel> Models { get; set; }
public ListCollectionView _collectionView;

public MyConstructor() 
{
    InitializeComponent();
    GetData();
    Grouping();
}

public void GetData() 
{
    // fill the list "Models"
}

public void Grouping()
{
    // _collectionView = null;
    _collectionView = new ListCollectionView(Models);
    _collectionView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("MyModelSupplier"));
    _collectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("MyModelSupplier", ListSortDirection.Ascending)); // LINE A
    _collectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("MyModelName", ListSortDirection.Ascending)); // LINE B
    ModelControl.ItemsSource = _collectionView;
}

private void OnDataChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Save the Data to the Database
    //...

    // Retrieve the Data
    GetData();

    // Group it again
    Grouping();
}
```

**To summarize:**

On startup everything looks and behaves like it should. Changing data, saving it to the `DataBase` and retrieving it again does work also. Just the sorting of the retrieved, grouped data won't work (the list is sorted - like default - by the first property of the MyModel class, which is MyModelName ... and NOT by MyModelSupplier, as it does in the very beginning).

**Edit:**
This is a known bug/missing feature (up until .NET 4.6.2). Several suggestions can be found here (I went with the last solution):

Bug-Report: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2017716/wpf-live-shaping-groups-are-not-sorted-correctly-after-a-property-changes

Simple Fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10121983/8187945

Comment: I think you need to use the LiveSorting / Grouping properties on the LCV. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview.islivesorting(v=vs.110).aspx (doing it in the code behind is the right way to do it). It can be a bit fiddly, but I do seem to remember getting it working once.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I wasted six hours of my lifetime.
SortDescriptions just worked for 1st time and I wasn't able to implement all offered solutions I found somewhere.

I decided to use CustomSort. After five minutes I was finished. So, if you read this, maybe you'll save time

The Solution 1 Part:

```
public class MyComparer : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        var a = x as CustomViewEntityViewModel;
        var b = y as CustomViewEntityViewModel;

        if (a == null || b == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Not My CustomViewEntityViewModel");

        if (a.SortOrder > b.SortOrder)  // I added property SortOrder to my viewmodel
            return 1;
        if (a.SortOrder == b.SortOrder)
            return 0;

        return -1;
    }
}
```

2nd Part: How to use

```
var myListCollectionView = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Filters);
myListCollectionView.CustomSort = new MyComparer();
myListCollectionView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Category"));

MyListCollectionView = myListCollectionView; // Which is binded by DG.ItemsSource
```

Comment: Thank you! I spent two days trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure why you are making your `ListCollectionView` in your VM as this is a part of `PresentationFramework.dll` so no MvvM in here.
However if you use `CollectionViewSource` in your xaml then this would be much easier!
in your xaml you would do:

```
<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Items}" x:Key="items">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="yourPropertyHere"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="propertyHere" />
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    <CollectionViewSource.LiveFilteringProperties>
        propertyNameHere
    </CollectionViewSource.LiveFilteringProperties>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

Where:

```
xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
```

and then use it for your `DataGrid` like so:
`<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource events}}"/>`

This gives you the ability to have these options in xaml and away from your view model.
You can also do this in code behind:
XAML:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="MyCVS"
                          Source="{Binding Items}"
                          Filter="My_Filter" />
```

and then in your code behind:

```
void My_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.Item as yourModelObject;
    if (item == <your test here>)
    {
        e.Accepted = true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Accepted = false;
    }
}
```

If you still have difficulties with the view not being refreshed then you could use this in your code behind to access the items being displayed and just refresh:

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lst.ItemsSource).Refresh();// where lst would be ListView or DataGrid
```

Comment: Thank you! I did it in XAML with CollectionViewSource, just as you described. It works EXACTLY the same as before :/

It was a missing feature/bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2017716/wpf-live-shaping-groups-are-not-sorted-correctly-after-a-property-changes.

Couldn't do it the way described there though. Finally found the working solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10121983/8187945

Comment: So, this is what I did:

    CollectionView collectionView = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ModelControl.ItemsSource);
    collectionView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
    collectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("MySupplierId", ListSortDirection.Ascending));

Comment: @Grent did the `Refresh();` method NOT included the sorting then?

Comment: Refresh() did not make any difference. Regarding LiveSorting: it didn't even have to do that. It should have only "kept" the same sorting as in the beginning, which it never did. So I had to clear the SortDescriptions and reset them.